# Error : import .graphql file in angular showing module not found

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

Actually I don't want to use any library like apollo-client or apollo-angular. So I generated a angular project with aws amplify. Then I got 3 files under src/graphql file those are mutations.graphql, queries.graphql & subscriptions.graphql. When I want to use those graphql file in my components it showing me this error constantly,

I tried to import like this,

```
import { GetProduct } from '../../graphql/queries.graphql';

Cannot find module '../../graphql/queries.graphql' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I saw several solutions but nothing is workout,

here is my tsconfig.ts file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/graphql"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

I also tried with `skipLibCheck` but still now not working.

I want to achieve this [Check at AMPLIFY Documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-graphql/image-and-file-uploads/q/platform/js/#interacting-with-the-api-from-a-client-application),

```
import { Storage, API } from 'aws-amplify';
import { getProduct } from './graphql/mutations';

async function getProductById () {
  const product = await API.graphql({ query: getProduct, variables: { id: "12345" }});
  const s3Image = await Storage.get(product.data.getProduct.image);
  product.data.getProduct.s3Image = s3Image;
  console.log('product:', product);
}
```

My only problem is I can't import `graphql` files , is there any thing that I missed to configure ? - TIA

Comment: Have you try adding the include property in your tsconfig file and list the src folder there? like so:  `"include": ["src/**/*"]` under the compilationOptions? This will help ts compiler recognize your referenced file

Comment: Does it work if you exclude the `.graphql` suffix? `import { GetProduct } from '../../graphql/queries;'`

Comment: @onrails i tried but not working.

Comment: @BizzyBob not working.